# how to check wether a get param is set or not?

Tags: java, spring, controller

Is it possible to differenciate those two request URIs in one controller handler :

```
http://my-uri/
http://my-uri/?with_empty_param
```

Comment: Using the `params` argument of the `@RequestMapping`.

Comment: Is its value null in both case ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with that comment... If it isn't present (no value or not existient) there is no value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpServletRequest object has a `ParameterMap` object that maps parameter name and its value.

With this map we can check if a parameter was passed in servlet request.

```
// Check if with_empty_param parameter exists
    if (request.getParameterMap().containsKey("with_empty_param ")) {
        String with_empty_param = request.getParameter("with_empty_param ");
    }
```

If you want to use Spring way you could do:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/init"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String methodName(
@RequestParam Map<String,String> allParams, ModelMap model) {
 if (allParams.containsKey("with_empty_param ")) {
  ...
 }
```

Comment: It sounds quite plain-JEE-like, I will do like this If  there's no other way.

Answer (score 1):

The [`@RequestMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) annotation has a [`params`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--) argument which you can use for that.

```
@RequestMapping
public void method1() {}
```

And with a check on the param.

```
@RequestMapping(params={"param"})
public void method2() {}
```

You can also use the `!` to negate the check, so if that param isn't present.

```
@RequestMapping(params={"!param"})
public void method3() {}
```